# Remote Login using cURL

Tags: curl

I'm trying to login a user who was authenticated elsewhere to a Joomla-site and was following [Brent Friar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-s/5207806#5207806) nice program, but had to apply two modifications:

1. added a field "return" which was contained in the form
2. refencing com_users, not com_user

I do not know if that site has specific customizations, uses a specific login-module or if is a different version - I do not have admin-access to the site, so I cannot check.
Now, my script is running, but it does not successfully login the user - it doesn't get a cookie in return which it is expecting.

Instead, the site returns

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>
> HTTP/1.1 303 See other Date: Wed, 23 Jul 2014 18:18:25 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.22 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17 Location:
>   http://www.strassenbau.forum-kundenportal.de/login-erfolgreich
>   Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8

I know a bit of Joomla, but know nothing about the depths of http-communication with it, so I have no idea what the problem is here.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$uname = "*** secret";
$upswd = "*** credentials";
$url = "http://www.strassenbau.forum-kundenportal.de/login-anmeldung";
set_time_limit(0);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
    preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
}

preg_match('/name="return" value="(.*)"/', $ret, $return); // search for hidden field "return" and get its value

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['password'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['option'] = 'com_users';
$postfields['task'] = 'user.login';
$postfields['return'] = $return[1];
$postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
// edit: using the location of the 303-result directly...but it does not make a difference
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://www.strassenbau.forum-kundenportal.de/login-erfolgreich");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

echo "ret2: <pre>"; var_dump($ret); echo "</pre>";  // no cooking being set here!

// Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
$cookie=explode('=',$m[1]);
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]);


?>
```

While looking for answers, I found a remark saying that Joomla now also uses session-tokens, so it would not work for that reason. Can anybody confirm that explanation? But how then is remote login handled in such situations? Could I overcome the issue by implementing my own login-module?

Comment: I'm not sure that your regex pattern is perform exactly as you intend.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380/2943403  <-  worth a look.  And the greedy quantifier here: `preg_match('/name="return" value="(.*)"/', $ret, $return)` looks vulnerable to overmatching.  Did you ever echo out what values are actually being matched/captured?

Comment: Without knowing more about this issue, I'd probably recommend something like: `if (preg_match('~\bname=["\']\K\w{32}~', $ret, $spoof)) { $token = $spoof[0]; } else { echo "Valid Token Not Found in $ret"; }` and `echo preg_match('~\bname=["\']return["\'] value=["\']\K[^"\']+~', $ret, $return) ? "Didn't get return value from $ret" : $return[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by using the **AutoLogin-Extension** (dead hyperlink to JED removed).

**Update**: that worked fine in the old days (Joomla 2), but the extension seems to be withdrawn, so I apologize if the solution won't help you these days.

Comment: I get "The extension is unpublished".

Comment: Sounds as if you have to publish the extension then (in Joomla)...

Comment: No, I mean the link is "broken".

Comment: LOL - sorry!! Totally stupid & wrong thoughts here :((

Comment: No problem. ;) But you should update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your authentication issue, you can just install **IP Login** and enable your IP: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=ip+

PD: Your *preg_match("/name=...* could be finding some other element, and not only the "return" token.

Comment: I do have admin-access to that site and installing anything there is a not possible, I'm afraid. After all, the script should be able to send back that form with a post-request, shouldn't it...?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "I do not have admin-access". Also, it should not work for my IP, but for the person that is logged in using my program...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```